# Integrability of an open and convex subset $M$ of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with non-empty interior and compact closure (e.g. $(0,1)\times(0,1))$

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms, riemann-integration

I will follow the definition of the volume of a Riemmanian manifold from page 422 of [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4419-9982-5)

Let $M$ be an open and convex subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with non-empty interior and compact closure (e.g. $(0,1)\times(0,1)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$). Such $M$ clearly defines a smooth manifold, and we could take, for example, the standard Euclidean metric as Riemannian metric $g$. However, in order to define the volume of $M$ defined by
$$
vol(M) = \int_M\omega_g,
$$
$M$ itself must be compact. However, e.g. $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ itself is not compact. Moreover, the indicator function $f:=1_M$ is neither compactly supported nor continuous, hence $vol(M)=\int_M f\omega_g$ does not make sense.

Intuitively speaking, as $\bar{M}$ is compact, the volume of $M$ is bounded. However, how can we rigorously define the volume of such $M$? For example, how can we construct $\omega_g$ such that the volume of $(0,1)\times(0,1)$ is 1. Or do we need any additional condition on $M$?

Comment: There is no need to assume compactness in the definition of Lebesgue integral.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you for the reply! I know that considering Lebesgue integral, the compactness assumption is not needed. However, I am trying to understand the Riemannian integral, starting from differential forms. How can I relate the Riemannian integral to Lebesgue integral? What is the differential form if we were to use Lebesuge integral?

Comment: For continuous functions on open subsets you get the same answer for Lebesgue and Riemann integration. But Lebesgue integral is more efficient as there is no need to distinguish proper and improper integrals.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Thank you again for the kind reply! I know that the Lebesgue measure, in this context, gives the same result. However, I need this to prove another theorem, so it must be done within the Riemannian framework. So if you could give me the answer with the Riemannian framework, I'd be really grateful!

Comment: The indicator function of an open set that is the interior of a Riemann integrable set is Riemann integrable.

Comment: @Deane Thank you for the comment! It would be really nice property! Could you provide any source or proof? Moreover, in such a case, I suppose you are saying that $\bar{M}$ is the Riemann integrable set. But then how can we show that $\bar{M}$ forms a smooth manifold? Thank you!

Comment: The definition in your book applies to manifolds-without-boundary that exist in and of themselves, not as embedded in some larger manifold. But you are trying to think of it in terms of its embedding in a larger manifold. The book definition is not the be-all end-all of integration of forms on smooth manifolds. The book gave a definition sufficient for its purposes, while you are operating outside those purposes. Examine what use the book makes of the compactness of $M$, then figure out how to accomplish those same purposes in your situation. That is how you generalize the definition.

Comment: @PaulSinclair Thank you for the suggestion! That's exactly what I was trying to do! However, I couldn't find any solution or to come up with nice generalisation. Hence, if you could give me some input that would be really nice!